# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am Getting this error
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Source Error:

> Line 153:         Session["Cat"] = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
>   Line 154:
>   Line 155:         Session["Cat_ID"] =
>   DataList3.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex].ToString();//error
>   Line 156:     Response.Redirect("Disp_Category.aspx?id=C"); 
>   Line 157:     }

Please some one what is wrong with this code

```
protected void DataList3_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
 {
     Session["L_Id"] = ddlLanguage.SelectedValue;
     Session["Cat"] = e.CommandArgument.ToString();

     Session["Cat_ID"] = DataList3.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex].ToString();
     Response.Redirect("Disp_Category.aspx?id=C");
 }
```

on aspx file i have this

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList3" runat="server" DataKeyNames="C_Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" OnItemCommand="DataList3_ItemCommand">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border=1 width=150>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("C_Name") %>'
                                                    Text='<%# Eval("C_Name") %>' CausesValidation="False"></asp:LinkButton></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:DataList><asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\New Projects\Sym\App_Data\Music.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
                                ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Category] ORDER BY [C_Name]">
                            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: What's wrong ? can't you read the error, DataList3.DataKeys array it doing out of range with the supplied value of e.Item.ItemIndex, just correct that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not right.
I suggest to set the id (c_id) and not the name (c_name) in `CommandArgument`.
That's your key. In `ItemCommand` you can get entire record by id.
Moreover:

```
Response.Redirect("Disp_Category.aspx?id=C");
```

becomes

```
Response.Redirect("~/Disp_Category.aspx?id=C");  //id=C? sure?
```